# MYSQL Error while calling stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure, but while calling I am getting below error.

Stored procedure is as follows

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `CreateTableProjectIssues`(IN projName     VARCHAR(200), IN tablName VARCHAR(200))
BEGIN
SET @comnd = CONCAT('create table ',tablName,' as ( select r1.key, s1.comments, p1.fname, s1.line, s1.status 
 FROM test.issues s1, test.proj p1, test.rules r1 
 WHERE s1.root_component_id=(select id from test.proj p2 
                                   where p2.name=''',projName,''') 
       and s1.component_id=p1.id 
       and s1.rule_id=r1.id');
 PREPARE stmt FROM @comnd;
 EXECUTE stmt;
END
```

And getting below error

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

Note: I know SQL query is badly formed, not used join.

Any idea why this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got a `(` too much. Try this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `CreateTableProjectIssues`(IN projName     VARCHAR(200), IN tablName VARCHAR(200))
BEGIN
SET @comnd = CONCAT('create table ',tablName,' as select r1.key, s1.comments, 

/*removed the (                             here ^  */

p1.fname, s1.line, s1.status 
 FROM test.issues s1, test.proj p1, test.rules r1 
 WHERE s1.root_component_id=(select id from test.proj p2 
                                   where p2.name=''',projName,''') 
       and s1.component_id=p1.id 
       and s1.rule_id=r1.id');
 PREPARE stmt FROM @comnd;
 EXECUTE stmt;
END
```